# Asp.Net WriteSubsitution vs PartialView - the right way

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a partial view that should not be cached in a output cached MVC view.
Usually you write non-cached content by using **Response.WriteSubstitution**.
The problem is that **WriteSubstitution** takes as a parameter a **HttpResponseSubstitutionCallback** callback which looks like this:

***public delegate string HttpResponseSubstitutionCallback(System.Web.HttpContext context)***

This is where things get complicated since there is no easy/fun way to generate the html on the fly.
You have to do a hack like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string).

So the question is: Is there an easier way to make a partial view not cached ?

Answer (score 0):

See Phil Haack's article on [donut caching in MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx).  Phil takes advantage of the existing API to create a new HtmlHelper method to provide a callback that can render the non-cached code.  His supplies an anonymous method to the helper to specify the callback.  To get this to work unchanged, you'll still need to have a method that renders a partial view to a string, though I think it would be easier to do in an HtmlHelper -- just look at the source for RenderPartial and RenderPartialInternal and see what changes would be needed to write it to a MemoryStream instead of the Response -- I believe it would be the same code except you'd supply your stream instead of the Response output stream, then convert your stream to a string.

It might look like this:

```
<%= Html.Substitute( cb => Html.RenderToString( "Partial" ) ) %>
```

Phil indicates that it might make it in to ASP.NET MVC 1.0, but I think it's only available in the [MvcFutures assembly](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23011#338501).

Answer (score 0):

In MVC2 we can use Html.Action to easily obtain the substituted html. Yeeeeiii
But Response.WriteSubstitotion is not working anymore. Aaaahhhh